# Binding data to a ListView inside user control (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, observablecollection

I have a user control like this

```
  <Grid>
    <ListView SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="lview"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="{x:Bind DisplayMemberPath}"  ></ListView>
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
 public sealed partial class UserCntrl : UserControl
{
    public UserCntrl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(UserControl),
         new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public string DisplayMemberPath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMemberPath", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

}
```

MainPage code

```
  <local:UserCntrl x:Name="lview"   Loaded="EditTextControl_Loaded"></local:UserCntrl>
```

Code behind

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EditTextControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<OptionItem> io = new ObservableCollection<OptionItem>();

        io.Add(new OptionItem { Name = "11111111111" });
        lview.ItemsSource = io;
        lview.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";

    }
}

public class OptionItem 
{
    private string _Name = string.Empty;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value;  }
    }

}
```

This gives an output like this

[image]

How can I make this control display correct items it contains, instead of the name of the model.
Complete code is available [here](https://filebin.net/aoapole5zr00act1). 
Note: I can't edit the model or the way I add content to the ObservableCollection. I have to make this work by editing the UC

Comment: Try adding `this.DataContext = this` in your UserControl constructor.

Comment: @Eldar tried not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ItemTemplate` for that:

```
<ListView...>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

It gives you great flexibitlity, when it comes to how to display an item :)

**EDIT**: Try defining dependency property for `ItemTemplate`

```
public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
{
    get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(UserControl));
```

Comment: for me, it may not be possible. I am creating a generic user control. So that it can accept different types of IEnumerable as Itemsource. inside each itemssource which is the field to be bound can't be set inside the user control. that data needs to come from the parent page through a dependency property. that is why I am using DisplayMemberPath

Comment: @None Then define the `ItemTemplate` property instead of `DisplayMemberPath` :)

Comment: I have already tried it like this, showing empty.  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding  DisplayMemberPath}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

Comment: @None Sorry, I used WPF `Binding` instead of `x:Bind` :) Try changing that.

Comment: Invalid binding path 'DisplayMemberPath' : Property 'DisplayMemberPath' not found on type 'DataTemplate'. This is what I get for x:bind

Comment: @None Did you change all dependency property declaration from `DisplayMemberPath` to `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: I have kept it ask it is now. My understanding is that, Both are just strings what ever name it have.

Comment: So that I can use them like this              <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DisplayMemberPath}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

Comment: Or can you please show me the full implementation of what you are suggesting. I think I am missing something here

Answer (score 1):

As @Michał Turczyn said, you can change data template to `Text="{x:Bind}"` will work.

Comment: Is there any other way to make it work without using ItemTemplate. My approach looks correct to me and I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Maybe you can give a full description of what you want, ie, the final result. Then we can find if there is other way or not.